# Postgres JOIN child as JSON

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I have a node server accessing a postgres database through a npm package, pg, and have a working query that returns the data, but I think it may be able to be optimized. The data model is of versions and features, one version has many feature children. This query pattern works in a few contexts for my app, but it looks clumsy. Is there a cleaner way?

```
SELECT 
v.*,
coalesce(
    (SELECT array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json(x))) FROM (select f.* from app_feature f where f.version = v.id) x ), 
    '[]'
) as features FROM app_version v


CREATE TABLE app_version(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    major INT NOT NULL,
    mid INT NOT NULL,
    minor INT NOT NULL,
    date DATE,
    description VARCHAR(256),
    status VARCHAR(24)
);

CREATE TABLE app_feature(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    version INT,
    description VARCHAR(256),
    type VARCHAR(24),

    CONSTRAINT FK_app_feature_version FOREIGN KEY(version) REFERENCES app_version(id)
);

INSERT INTO app_version (major, mid, minor, date, description, status) VALUES (0,0,0, current_timestamp, 'initial test', 'PENDING');
INSERT INTO app_feature (version, description, type) VALUES (1, 'store features', 'New Feature')
INSERT INTO app_feature (version, description, type) VALUES (1, 'return features as json', 'New Feature');
```

Answer (score 1):

The subquery in `FROM` clause may not be needed.

```sql
select v.*,
       coalesce((select array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json(f))) 
                   from app_feature f 
                  where f.version = v.id), '[]') as features 
  from app_version v;
```

Comment: thank you, exactly the type of tuning help i was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

And my 5 cents. Pls. note that `id` is primary key of `app_version` so it's possible to group by `app_version.id` only.

```sql
select v.*, coalesce(json_agg(to_json(f)), '[]') as features 
from app_version v join app_feature f on f.version = v.id
group by v.id;
```

Comment: funny, this is one of the first FK relationships ive built in this app and it looks like theres a tangible benefit in this use case

Comment: @textual Old school good practices pay off :)

Answer (score 0):

You could move the JSON aggregation into a view, then join to the view:

```
create view app_features_json
as
select af.version,
       json_agg(row_to_json(af)) as features
from app_feature af
group by af.version;
```

The use that view in a join:

```
SELECT v.*,
       fj.features 
FROM app_version v
  join app_features_json afj on afj.version = v.id
```

Comment: hmm, would there be a performance gain at some volume where having this view is more economical than converting to json within the query?

Comment: @textual: yes, this is likely to be faster that a co-related subquery that is called once for each version.